# Unable to pass non-nullable FormState to child widget

Tags: flutter

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: BarWidget(_formKey.currentState),
    );
  }
}

// In another library. 
class BarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final FormState? _formState;
  BarWidget(this._formState);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_formState); // Prints null 
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

I'm providing `FormState` to `BarWidget` but I am getting `null` in it (maybe because the `Form` is not rendered yet). So, what's the right approach to get a non-nullable `FormState`?

---

**Some workarounds:**

1. Convert `FooPage` to `StatefulWidget`, and use `addPostFrameCallback()` on either `SchedulerBinding` or `WidgetBinding` to call `setState`.
2. Use `Future`/`Timer` to call `setState`.
3. Use an `async` marked function in the `FooPage`'s `build()` to call `setState`.
4. Instead of passing `FormState`, pass `FormState Function() callback` to get the `FormState`.
5. Passing the `GlobalKey` itself and then accessing the `FormState` in the child widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 5. Passing the GlobalKey itself and then accessing the FormState in the child widget.

is the best one listed, Also your code is more null safe.

Another option is to use `Form.of(context)` which will get you the nearest `FormState`. this one is more straightforward, but it's less safe, since `BarWidget` might be in part of the tree where there's no `Form` ancestor.

```
// In another library. 
class BarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(Form.of(context));
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

You can use asserts, naming or library-private code to make this option more safe.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how good it is to pass keys.

Comment: IMHO using `Form.of(context)` is the best and recommended way to access state, you don't need to do any of these, `InheritedWidget` does the job, you just need to be more safe while using it, specially in your use case